# Can't generate war - Java EE 8

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

After create a new Java EE project - in IntelliJ - new project -> Gradle from left list -> next -> next
I fill 2 files

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'

group 'com.random'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.1'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

and

```
@Path("/reservation")
public class ReservationWebService {
    @GET
    public Response listReservations() {
        return Response.ok("hello").build();
    }
}
```

now I'm trying to generate war by: 
`gradle war` in terminal and I got:

> 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

How to generate war ?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: It seems you can't reach gradle's bin folder. Have you set GRADLE_HOME path?

Comment: I have gradle :) in windows console gradle -v works, but in terminal IntellJ i still get "is not recognized"